# Wait for variable to change before running another function?

Tags: javascript

My script is set up like this:

```
function apiGrab() {
   changingVar = something grabbed from an API;
}

function apiDisplay() {
   alert(changingVar);
}
```

But the problem is, whenever the *apiDisplay* function runs, the API hasn't quite finished getting the information I need. If I were to use the *apiDisplay* function again after a few seconds (I run it with a button), it would display my information correctly it because I gave the API time to grab the variable.

Are there any solutions that I can use to give apiDisplay a short delay (if there any other possible solutions, please suggest them <3)?

Comment: Does your API has an option to accept a call-back function?